# Drupal + Hybridauth send activation email

Tags: drupal, hybridauth

I need send e-mail for activation user after HybridAuth add user in drupal 7.

My user is registered with HybridAuth Social and enter directly in my restrict area.

I like a activation before enter in my restrict area.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HybridAuth Social Login module (https://drupal.org/project/hybridauth):

1. Go to module settings page (admin/config/people/hybridauth)
2. Click on "Account settings" tab
3. Choose appropriate option under "E-mail verification" section.

It can be "Follow core: Require e-mail verification" (if you have enabled e-mail verification in Drupal core, on page admin/config/people/accounts) or "Require e-mail verification".